# Play short sounds rapidly in .NET or Win32

Tags: windows, audio, real-time

I need to play a short sound 60+ times per second in my application.  The triggering pattern is not known in advance, so I can't make one big file that contains 60 repeats of the same sound.  The sound needs to play asynchronously.

C#'s `SoundPlayer` and Win32's `PlaySound()` both appear to start a separate thread each time you ask to play a sound asynchronously.  I don't want the overhead of creating so many threads, so I can't use those options.  In addition, if the sound gets triggered again while a previous trigger is still playing, the sound should restart or play overlapped rather than queueing up to be played later.

Are there any pre-baked .NET or Win32 tools that can do this?  Right now I'm thinking I need a lower level solution built with manual threading and events.

Comment: 60+ times per *second*, is that a typo?

Comment: Nope, that is what I meant.  The sounds should be allowed to overlap or cut each other off.

Comment: There are *many* audio libraries that do a much better job that tired old Windows 3's PlaySound.  Look at the kind that are used in game development.